chakra-ui v3 doesn't work with vite and react
I am following this tutorial:
Build and Deploy an Instagram Clone with React and Firebase – Tutorial
Which uses the package.json:
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.1.1",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^3.2.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.13.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.3",
    "eslint": "^9.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.37.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.14",
    "globals": "^15.11.0",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}

The front end is rendered using this main.jsx:
import { StrictMode } from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import { Provider } from "@/components/ui/provider"
import { defaultSystem } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider value={defaultSystem}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>,
)


As usual, main.jsx is rendered in index.html, snippet as follows:
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>

I also followed the documentation for upgrading chakra-ui from 2 to 3 as in the link
As you may imagine, this involves npm uninstall/install of the packages including ui provider and also other troubleshooting steps such as - delete node_modules etc and recreate the dependencies.
This shows the logs, which are fine:

added 367 packages, and audited 368 packages in 16s
104 packages are looking for funding   run npm fund for details
found 0 vulnerabilities

However running the command:
npm run dev -- --host=127.0.0.1

gives the following error:

  VITE v4.5.5  ready in 281 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5174/
  ➜  press h to show help
Error: The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved:

  @/components/ui/provider (imported by C:/Users/PC/Code/nodejs/reactjs/instagram-clone/instagram-clone/vite-project/src/main.jsx)

Are they installed?
at file:///C:/Users/PC/Code/nodejs/reactjs/instagram-clone/instagram-clone/vite-project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-b2890f90.js:45779:23
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async file:///C:/Users/PC/Code/nodejs/reactjs/instagram-clone/instagram-clone/vite-project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-b2890f90.js:45187:38

This is strange, as far as I think of, I don't see why this can't be installed by npm install.  Or may be I clearly have to think outside of the yarn/npm world.  Any pointers or help is greatly appreciated.


The error refers the import from your project, @/components/ui/provider, which doesn't exist. It's not affected by Chakra.
The doc you linked explains this,

The Provider component compose the ChakraProvider from Chakra and ThemeProvider from next-themes

You're supposed to write provider yourself.
This is also covered in the docs. For a theme provided as value prop it would be:
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes"

export function Provider(props) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider value={props.value}>
      <ThemeProvider>
        {props.children}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
} 


Thanks for your response. I added a theme/theme.ts. Here my basic use case is "Color Mode" as in subsection-from-provided-doc.  So basically, I have this in theme.ts, a snippet:
const config: ThemeConfig = {
initialColorMode: "light", // Set the initial color mode (e.g., 'light' or 'dark')
useSystemColorMode: true, // Use system preferences to toggle color mode
};
Now I have also wired the Provider.tsx and in turn in existing main.tsx. But wonder why .tsx and not .jsx as chakra-ui snippets are jsx

The examples in the docs use TS. If you don't use it in your project, you can strip ts types from code and work with js/jsx files

Maybe you forget to run
npx @chakra-ui/cli snippet add
It will installed required dependencies and add recommended snippets, It will also create provider.tsx in you src/components/ui.
Here is link to read more
https://www.chakra-ui.com/docs/get-started/frameworks/vite#add-snippets

{
"@chakra-ui/react": "^3.2.1",
"@emotion/react": "^11.14.0",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.14.0",
"framer-motion": "^6.5.1",
"react": "^18.3.1",
"react-dom": "^18.3.1"

},
chakra-ui v3 doesn't work with vite and react
the best and easy
"@chakra-ui/react": "^3.2.1",
to change the version manually to 2.0.0
"@chakra-ui/react": "^2.0.0",

and ReInstall the package
npm install
its works ,try it ....
